# How to get json from MVC4 C# with no javascript and no Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I get the feeling I really should be learning WCF for this (feel free to comment if you agree), but, I want to query a website and get a result back, in either XML or JSON format.

In this case, I'm choosing JSON.

I have a controller in a web site (www.site1.com) , which looks like

```
public JsonResult Save(bool willSave)
{
   //logic with the parameters to go here
   return Json(new { code = 200, description = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now, I'd like to get this information from another website, so in www.site2.com I have nothing... I have no idea what code I can write, simply because all of the examples I've seen where you query json uses javascript/Ajax.

I don't want to use JavaScript or Ajax (I know how to do that), for this project I'm trying to do everything I can server side.

I'd like to be able to do the following

```
public ActionResult Do() 
{
    var json = someHowQuerySite1.com?withQueryString=true;//THIS IS THE ISSUE
    var model = CreateModel(json);
    return View(model);
}
```

As you can hopefully see,

```
var json = someHowQuerySite1.com?withQueryString=true;//THIS IS THE ISSUE
```

I don't know what syntax to write here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way, replace

```
var json = someHowQuerySite1.com?withQueryString=true;
```

with

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var responseString = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx?withQueryString=true");

    var json = myJsonUtililty.toJson(responseString);
}
```

[HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a HttpWebRequest to request www.site1.com/Save?save=true. Something like

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://[urlhere]");
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using(Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
 //Get your JSON from the stream here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("UserApi/ValidateUserLogin", new UsersBLL { Username = userName, UserPassword = password }).Result;
```

Comment: That really looks like you're passing a password as plain text in this example. is that the normal way to do it?

Comment: If u are using SSL then only u can pass plan text in password, else u can use some custom encryption / decryption .